# I need to fill a matrix by valued taken from such vector

Tags: python, matlab

I have an issue, for example, I have a vector `X` of length `32x1`  and a matrix `M` of size `(32,32)` I need to copy values of vector `X` into the matrix `M`. for example I have done this using Matlab as below :

```
clear all; clc; 
X = randn(32,1); 
M = zeros(length(X),length(X));
for i = 1: length(X)
    M(i:length(X),i) = X(1:length(X)-i+1);
end
```

how can I do that in python, I tried doing it as below, but I get an issue !!

```
import numpy as np
X= np.random.random(32,)
X_len = len(X)
s = (X_len ,X_len )
M= np.zeros(s, dtype=int)
for i in range(X_len):
    M[i: X_len , i] = X[0: X_len - i]
```

I think that's not right!!  it gives an error.  That matrix `M` is still with values zeros !! it doesn't change, however the code doesn't give an error !

thanks in advance

Comment: "I think that's not right!! it gives an error" Can you be more specific?

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: @AnderBiguri   I updated the question,  The matrix M doesn't change, it keeps being zeros !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just should replace `M= np.zeros(s, dtype=int)` by this command `M= np.zeros(s)` and check.  It must be ok.